# Can we have two explicit waits in the same program

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have two explicit waits in the same program. One for WaitForElement and one WaitForPageLoad.But it doesn't seem to work. When i change one of them to implicit wait, it works fine. Otherwise the code fails at the begining itself.Beginner in selenium so no idea why it failed.

Error:

```
 NoSuchElementException
```

waits:have used these in two different methods

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    {
       IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
       {
          return d.FindElement(By.ClassName("header"));
       });
       if (myDynamicElement != null) return true;
    }

  WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    {
       IWebElement _myDynamicElement = _wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
       {
          return d.FindElement(By.ClassName("header-buttons"));
       });
       if (_myDynamicElement != null) return true;
    }
```

code where the method is used in the program

```
   WaitForElementPresent(By.CssSelector("div[class='tagged-text search-text']>input"));
 //Enter the item to search
   driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='tagged-text search-text']>input")).Clear();
   driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='tagged-text search-text']>input")).SendKeys(searchItem + Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: In your first code block, it looks like you have an errant `}` after your `if (myDynamicElement != null) return true;` line. Is this intended?

Comment: Sorry. Typed it wrongly. I have edited the code.

Comment: @user1177636, I want to use these methods in places where I want to wait.I have taken a random classname(header) from the page and used it. So when i want to wait for a element to load, I use WaitforElement(By.classname("something")). What should be used there actually ?

Comment: @user1177636, But when I use these 2 waits in two different methods and call them in my program, it fails at the beginning itself. When I change one of them to implicit it works.

Comment: the exception was thrown in the line where i used the waitforelement(By...) which was the second line in the program. When i call this wait method it fails. but when using implicit the test proceeds (with the same wait statement in the second line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more generic approach to waiting for an element would be better for your uses. So instead use a generic expression and pass in your search criteria. For example:

```
public void WaitForElementById(string elementId, int timeout = 5)
{
    //Where '_driver' is the instance of your WebDriver
    WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout));
    IWebElement element = _wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id(elementId)));
}
```

This will throw an exception if the wait times out so you could also adding in a try/catch to report failings differently. I personally use this in my testing solution within a switch that has a case for each of my commonly used search types. I then pass in the **search type** and the **search term** (eg, elementAttribute ID, string myTextboxID).

With that said, I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code that would cause it not to work.

Comment: I tried this code .. it gives an ElementNotVisibleException and stops. In the explicit wait what does 'somedynamicelement' mean? code:return d.FindElement(By.ClassName("somedynamicelement")); does it refer to any random classname on that page?

Comment: An `ElementNotVisibleException` suggests that it has found the element via the identifier you provided but the element itself is not set as visible for the user. This means it is disabled in some way.
Not sure what you mean by 'somedynamicelement', where is that written? In your code?

Comment: the 'header' and 'header-buttons'. I got this wait from seleniumhq.org

Comment: IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
    });

Comment: The string `"someDynamicElement"` there is referring to the target elements ID. You are supposed to provide the id of whatever error you are targeting there. However, this code does the same as the example I provided (to my knowledge at least).

Comment: Sorry, One more question, in your wait you have given a _driver which shows a red line in my pgm, so I changed it to driver, Is this the reason why its not working? becoz i have another driver in explicit wait so shld i create another instance of it(_driver) and use it. (both the wait methods point to the same driver) So shld i have one in the explicit as driver and another as _driver.Might be a silly question but i doubt if thats the reason.

Comment: My apologies, I grabbed this from some code I had lying around. See my edit with comment added to my code. The `_driver` is just what I have called my instance of WebDriver (eg. the variable name). Yours is most likely named something else and thus `_driver` does not exist in your code's context. So you are right - you should use your variable name `driver` instead.

Comment: Thanks alot. when i use 'driver' the wait statement works fine.